# Single activity app with Navigation Component and Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I want to create a Single Activity app which will contain for simplicity only the following screens:
Landing, Login, Register, Home, Profile. The Home and Profile screens will be visible to the user only if is logged in and will belong to a Navigation Drawer.

Unfortunately what comes to my mind is to create an Activity with nav_graph_1, that contains the following destinations: Landing, Login, Register.
Then create another Activity with nav_graph_2 (Home and Profile destinations) that will contain all the setup for the Navigation Drawer: e.g. `setupActionBarWithNavController`, appBarConfiguration with the nav_graph_2 and the drawer.

Is it possible to implement the above in a Single Activity app and how?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to implement the above in a Single Activity app and how?

Short Answer: yes, it's possible.

**Long Answer:**

> what comes to my mind is to create an Activity with nav_graph_1, that contains the following **destinations: Landing, Login, Register.** Then create another Activity with nav_graph_2 (**Home and Profile destinations**) that will contain all the setup for the Navigation Drawer

**I assume that your main issue for having a single activity model:** is that you have a container that you suggested to be as your second activity because of having sub-containers in it (Drawer fragments). You can do that if you wish, but you can also use a single activity and multiple fragments arranged in cascaded nav graphs like in below navigation graph scheme.

[image]

- The landing fragment is considered the root fragment of your activity.
- Your activity layout has a `FragmentContainerView` that can host login register, and main fragments
- After the user login, you switch to the main fragment
- Like the main activity layout, the main fragment layout just has a `FragmentContainerView` for its sub-fragments. Where you can create a new navigation graph for it which contains Home and Profile fragments.

Here you have 2 navigation graph, the first contains 4 fragments (landing, login, register, and main), and the other contains 2 fragments (home and profile).

So, your in your example you've 2 navigation graphs:

**Graph 1**

[image]

**Graph 2**

[image]

Comment: What's the best practice for doing this now? What if I need to have a bottom navigation view for the user once they are authenticated? Should I place the bottom navigation view in the activity itself and hide it while being authenticated? Or is there any other way?